# Concatenate YAML file with predefined values inside custom tag

Tags: yaml, serverless-framework

I'm trying to write a Serverless Framework file that will be a "master" template. This template could then be used by a user with a "child" serverless file. This would allow me to keep a global configuration, while allowing some freedom to the users consuming the template.

In particular, because we are using the [`serverless-python-requirements` plugin](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-python-requirements), I want to make sure that all serverless files include at least the following `custom` values:

```yaml
custom: 
  pythonRequirements:
    pipCmdExtraArgs:
      - "--platform manylinux2014_x86_64"
      - "--only-binary=:all:"
```

But because some people might use the `custom` keyword as well for other things, I want to make sure their values are included as well.

I've stumbled upon [this forum post](https://forum.serverless.com/t/merging-environment-configs/5125), which seems to be able to solve my issue, but after many tries, I couldn't find a way to make this works. This is what I tried:

```yaml
default_python_requirements: &default_python_requirements
  pythonRequirements:
    pipCmdExtraArgs:
      - "--platform manylinux2014_x86_64"
      - "--only-binary=:all:"

custom: 
  <<: *default_python_requirements
  ${file(custom.yml):custom, null}
```

But unfortunately, I got the following error message when trying to run `sls deploy`:

```
Cannot parse "serverless.yml": can not read an implicit mapping pair; a colon is missed in "serverless.yml"

 51 | custom: 
 52 |   <<: *default_python_requirements
 53 |   ${file(custom.yml):custom, null}
----------------------------------------^
```

I believe this is because yaml expects a key-value, and thinks that `custom.yml` file is only a key.

So how can I manage to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that this happens because your last line isn't a key value pair.

Serverless replaces this with a *complete* mapping. You can't lexically prepend the `<<` key and its corresponding value with it, because variable replacement happens *after* lexically parsing the input.

One thing you can try is this:

```yaml
custom: 
  <<: [*default_python_requirements, ${file(custom.yml):custom, null}]
```

Theoretically, this merges both the default requirements and the items from your `custom.yml` into the target mapping.

*However*, this has two preconditions which I think are unlikely to both be true:

- Serverless must support the `<<` key. This is an optional extension for outdated YAML 1.1. YAML implementations like PyYAML do implement it but I don't know which one Serverless is using.
- Serverless must replace variables *before* the YAML backend processes `<<`. Although possible with most implementations I know of that support `<<`, the variable replacement code must be specifically engineered for this use-case, as the common approach with typical YAML APIs would do any such post-processing *after* `<<` has been processed.

I don't know or use Serverless so I don't have a testing setup and can't test this for you. If you try this and it works, great! If it doesn't, one of the preconditions isn't true.